# Why in Roblox it's not possible to use `Intance.new(type)` with some type of objects?

Tags: lua, roblox

Using `Instance.new` on some types of objects such as

```
Instance.new('Animate')
Instance.new('UnionOperator')
```

trigger the error

```
Unable to create an Instance of type "Animate"
```

Why and how to programmatically create these instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `Animate` isn't a [class name in the Roblox engine](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes).

[image: A snapshot of a character model's object heirarchy in the Explorer and Properties widgets when the game is running]

As you can see from this example when the game is running, the Animate object in a character model is a LocalScript. You might be thinking of an [Animator](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Animator). But an Animator is also created automatically if you use `Humanoid:LoadAnimation()`, you don't have to create one manually.

But to answer your question, there are some class types that simply cannot be created. These classes are flagged in the documentation as `Not Creatable`. For example : [BrowserService](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BrowserService). These kinds of `Not Creatable` objects come with the tooltip

> You cannot create an instance of this class with the Instance.new constructor.

But for your example, a `UnionOperation` and an `Animator` object are both creatable.

Comment: thanks. so an Aninamte object in studio is a "sugar object" for a script that somehow makes the player animate (for example, when they walked)? So to better understand how I can create a similar object.

Comment: The Animate object is a LocalScript whose logic drives your animations. When you test your game double click on it to open it in the Script Editor. Read its contents and go from there. Heck, you can copy and paste the contents into a new script if you wanted.